# showOnLockScreen makes Fingerprint not responding on some devices

Tags: android

It is an activity that run on screen lock
which works fine 
1- lock device
2-my app starts and turns screen on and show its activity over lock/home-clock screen
but in some devices like Samsung J5 fingerprint do not respond anymore as long as my app is running, only when I close the app, and become in the regular home screen it works and unlock, on some other device like s8 and s9 it works great.
there is no errors or logs so I don't know what code I should attach, here is manifest and window flags:

```
    <!-- language: lang-xml -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.www.MainActivity"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and flags:

```
<!-- language: lang-JAVA -->
 private void setFullScreen() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

what could the problem be?

Comment: Tried to remove FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD, did not help. Still locking for an explanation at least why

Comment: still looking for any litle explination to start with

Comment: I'm not locking the device programmatically only run the app after it locks itself

Comment: Did you ever find out how to fix this? I'm having the same issue.